# simplifying the range of two definite integrals

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Today, I tried to obtain the solution of the following equation,

```
sol = DSolve[ {m v'[t] + \[Gamma] v[t] == \[Xi][t] , v[0] == v0}, v[t], t]
```

The solution, of course, can be easily obtained and the result was,

$$ \left\{\left\{v(t)\to e^{-\frac{\gamma  t}{m}} \left(-\int_1^0 \frac{\xi (K[1]) e^{\frac{\gamma  K[1]}{m}}}{m} \, dK[1]+\int_1^t \frac{\xi (K[1]) e^{\frac{\gamma  K[1]}{m}}}{m} \, dK[1]+\text{v0}\right)\right\}\right\}$$

This is correct solution but I am surprised that two integrals were present in this solution. Then, I tried to simplify using functions like `FullSimplify` and so on, but I failed to simplify it. Is there any automatic way to accomplish this goal?

I am using Mathematica 10.0 on the linux machine.

Comment: to further simplify you need to know something about the range of t. try specifying assumptions.

Comment: @george2079: Thank you. I tried to add some assumptions by defining `$Assumptions = {\[Gamma] > 0, m > 0, t > 0, v0 > 0};`. But, at least, this approach does not give a simpler form.

Comment: mathematically you need `0<=t<=1` to consolidate that to a single integral (from 0 to t). (I don't know if mathematica will do the simplify even under that assumption though)

Comment: @george2079 I am not very sure that your condition `0<= t<= 1` is really needed. Anyway, this additional assumption does not give a simpler solution. Thank you anyway.

Comment: right of course, caught me commenting before my second cup of coffee.  I'll point out you can show this more simply as `Integrate[ f[x] , {x, 0, 1} ] + Integrate[ f[x] , {x, 1, t } ]` does not simplify under any assumptions I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might handle this with a `TransformationFunction`:

```
 Simplify[ 
    Integrate[ f[x] , {x, 0, 1} ] + Integrate[ f[x] , {x, 1, t } ] ]
 t[s_Plus?(
      Length[#] == 2 &&
      Head[#[[1]]] == Integrate &&
      Head[#[[2]]] == Integrate &&
      #[[1, 1]] == #[[2, 1]] &&
      #[[1, 2, 3]] == #[[2, 2, 2]] &)] := 
       Integrate[s[[1, 1]], {s[[1, 2, 1]], s[[1, 2, 2]], s[[2, 2, 3]]}]
 Simplify[ 
    Integrate[ f[x] , {x, 0, 1} ] + Integrate[ f[x] , {x, 1, t } ] , 
    TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic , t }]
```

[image]

I'm sure this can be made cleaner and more robust..for example you need to deal with reversing limits and changing signs, and so on (eg:)

```
 t[s_Times?(#[[1]] == -1 &&  Head[#[[2]] ] == Integrate &)] :=
    Integrate[s[[2, 1]], {s[[2, 2, 1]], s[[2, 2, 3]], s[[2, 2, 2]]}]
 t[s_Plus?(
        Length[#] == 2 &&
        Head[#[[1]]] == Integrate &&
        Head[#[[2]]] == Integrate &&
        #[[1, 1]] == #[[2, 1]] &&
        #[[1, 2, 3]] == #[[2, 2, 2]] &)] := 
             Integrate[s[[1, 1]], {s[[1, 2, 1]], s[[1, 2, 2]], s[[2, 2, 3]]}]
 Simplify[ -Integrate[ f[x] , {x, 1, 0} ] + Integrate[ f[x] , {x, 1, t } ] , 
         TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic , t }]
```

> same result

For your example this works if you do:

```
 Simplify[sol /. v0 -> 0, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, t }]
```

to be more general you'd need to coax simplify to test every combination of terms in multi term sum.